# ModalDialog PostBack before closing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome

I have a project where I bring up a modal dialog that allows a user to add a new user to the system. Ideally the user would click a button that says "Add" which does a post back and then closes. The problem I have is that while debugging the Javascript I see it runs over the __doPostBack() call but the post back code never gets run. The code for the button is as follows:

```
__doPostBack("ADDUSER", "");
var Added = true;
var NewUserAdded = new Array(Added);
window.returnValue = NewUserAdded;
window.close();
```

This seems to work fine in IE8+ and Firefox but Chrome does not seem to actually execute the post back. Any help on this would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using 
`__doPostBack('ADDUSER','OnClick');` 
 If you have included jquery in your file then you can also try 
`$('ADDUSER').click();`
or
`$('ADDUSER').trigger('click');`